# Problema comprobar campos formulario php

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un archivo "validaciones.js" con la función comprobarPROFESOR(); para comprobar los campos de un formulario. 
En síntesis mi archivo de php queda así:

```
<table>
            <h1><?php echo $strings['ADD']; ?></h1> 
            <form name = 'Form' id="Form" action='../Controller/PROFESOR_Controller.php?action=ADD' method='post' onsubmit="return comprobarPROFESOR();">
                <tr>
                    <th><?php echo $strings['DNI']; ?> :</th> <td>
                    <input type = 'text' name = 'DNI' id = 'DNI' placeholder = 'Nombre' size = '15' value = '' onblur="comprobarVacio('DNI') && comprobarDni('DNI')" ><br></td>
                 </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <th><?php echo $strings['Nombre']; ?>:</th> <td><input type = 'text' name = 'NOMBREPROFESOR' id = 'NOMBREPROFESOR' placeholder = 'Nombre' size = '15' value = '' onblur="comprobarVacio('NOMBREPROFESOR') && comprobarAlfabetico('NOMBREPROFESOR',15)" ><br></td>
                    </tr>

                <div class="action_form_icon">

                    <form id="boton" action="../Controller/PROFESOR_Controller.php?action=ADD" method="post" onsubmit ="return comprobarPROFESOR();" >
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="ADD"/>
                            <button type="submit"><img src="../View/Icons/ok_icon.png" alt="Ok" width="25" height="25"></button>
                    </form>
                    </div>          
            </form>

</table>
```

El resultado es que me comprueba los campos pero cuando le doy al botón de añadir no ocurre nada. Si pongo el formulario del botón fuera del otro sucede al revés, me añade los valores pero no comprueba los campos.

Answer (score 1):

No tiene sentido poner un formulario dentro de otro. Los botones tienen que ir directamente en el formulario.

En el caso de ponerlo así no te v a comprobar si en la función comprobarPROFESOR(); no pones un preventDefault() para evitar que se envíe el formulario por defecto. Y luego si se cumple tu comprobación ya manualmente lanzas el submit sobre el formulario.

Un consejo: planteate sacar todo el código JavaScript a un archivo .js y dejar mas limpio el HTML.